# Continuous functions that are not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm writing some lecture notes on Riemann/Darboux integration and I recently finished the proof that continuous implies that the Riemann integral exists. The proof of the statement relies on showing that continuous functions defined in an interval are uniformly continuous.

As i finished doing that part, I started wondering: what are all the continuous functions that are not uniformly continuous. I know that functions with fast growing and with fast oscilation are in this category ($f(x) = e^x$ or $f(x) = \sin{(e^x)}$). Is there any other example (not explicit example, i don't care about what are all the functions, I want all the classes of functions that have a similar look and that have some property that make them non-uniformly continuous)?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ might be the easiest example of a continuous function which is uniformly continuous. Similarly $f(x)=x^a$ with $a>1$.

Comment: Oh, i guess that this goes into the "fast growing" category, but thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837681/examples-of-not-uniformly-continuous-non-differentiable-non-periodic-functio .

Comment: When we study Riemann integration, it is understood that we are on a bounded closed interval $[a,b].$ In that setting, "continuous functions are uniformly continuous" as you wrote. But then you ask for continuous functions that are not uniformly continuous. Then we are not on an interval suitable for Riemann integration. There is some mixing up of ideas here.

Comment: Oh, yeah, i know that, maybe I was just not as clear as i'd like. I for sure don't mind that the examples that I ask for are not defined in closed intervals (compact sets) for sure, I know that in a compact set, continuous implies uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^2$ might be the easiest example of a continuous function which is uniformly continuous. Similarly $f(x)=x^a$ with $a>1$.

More generally if $f$ is differentiable and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f'(x)|=\infty$$
then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on any interval $[a,\infty[$. This does formalize your notions of "fast growing" and "fast oscillation".

Comment: Thanks! Yes, indeed this is what I was meaning with fast growing and fast oscilation. Is there any other interesting condition that makes the function not uniformly continuous? It does not need to be a one of a kind, I'm just looking for the most common examples.

Comment: Well from the definition, uniform continuity means that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is not allowed to grow faster than $|x-y|$, which ties to my condition on $|f'(x)|$.

Comment: When we study Riemann integration, it is understood that we are on a bounded closed interval $[a,b].$ In that setting, "continuous functions are uniformly continuous" as you wrote. But then you ask for continuous functions that are not uniformly continuous. Then we are on an interval unsuitable for Riemann integration. There is some mixing up of ideas here.